# Question from Lance's book: showing a bounded operator $\leq 1$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

I wonder if someone could help me to understand the following sentence in the second last paragraph below: "Then $0\leq q\leq 1.$"

This extract is taken from the book of E. Christopher Lance on Hilbert modules.

The context is that $t$ is a densely defined regular operator between Hilbert modules $E$ and $F$. We know that the extension of the inverse $(1+t^*t)^{-1}$, which is referred to as $q$, is a positive element, which explains the first half of that sentence. But I'm not sure why $q\leq 1$, since $1+t^*t$ itself is not an element of $\mathcal{L}(E)$ so you can't just invert.

Many thanks for your help.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the second sentence of the second paragraph, $(1+t^*t)^{-1}$ is norm-reducing (on its domain).  Hence its bounded extension is norm-reducing, and so is this extension's square root, which we call $q$.  In other words, $\|q\|\leq1$, which implies $q\leq1$.

Comment: Why does $||q||\leq 1$ imply $q\leq 1$ in the algebra? I only know that the converse holds.

Comment: $\|q\|\leq1$ means $|\lambda|\leq1$ for all $\lambda\in\sigma(q)$.  Since $q$ is positive, $\sigma(q)\subset[0,1]$, so $\sigma(1-q)\subset[0,1]$ and thus $1-q\geq0$.

Comment: Ah yes, spectral radius is bounded above by norm. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome.  Glad to help!